# Four GUIs off USB Boot

Tags: boot, usb, graphics, gui, mac

I am booting Ubuntu on a mac off of a USB drive. When I start it up there is a black screen giving me the options to try Ubuntu, install Ubuntu, or 2 other options. I select try Ubuntu and four GUIs show up, one for each corner of the screen. The color in each is relatively faint and the words are unreadable. Is there a clear way to fix this? Thanks for the help.

iMac, Late 2009; Intel Core 2 Duo Processor, 4gb ram.

[image: 4 separate guis in each corner of a monitor]

Comment: I put the information you asked for in the original post. I couldnt get an actual screen shot so I just took a picture. It looks like low image quality, but those are the actual colors.

Comment: That works, gives a good idea of what you are seeing.

Comment: I don't know how relevant this is, but in the rEFIT menu thing it has two options for starting out of the USB drive, one with the text EFI/something/bootx64 on it and the other saying EFI/something/grub . Both produce the same result though.